# How to use JSON array to check if criteria is met correctly | Swift

Tags: ios, swift

How can I check if all rows in a tableview contain an checkmark accessory? I currently have a tableview that has checkmarks that appear if the user selects on the row. Checkmarks also appear on tableview once the TableViewController loads and JSON criteria is met for example

**Can allSatisfy be used to check if checkbox = 1 for all records in the array?**

**JSON Decodable Structure:**

```
struct JSONStruct: Decodable {
    let code: String
    var checkbox: Int
    
    var isSelected : Bool {
        get { return checkbox == 1 }
        set { checkbox = newValue ? 1 : 0 }
    }
    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case code, checkbox
    }
}
```

**cellForRowAt:**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        let item = structure[indexPath.row]
        cell.accessoryType = item.isSelected ? .checkmark : .none
```

Once a button is pressed I would like to display an error if all rows in the tableview do not have an accessory type checkmark. How can I check for this?

```
var structure = [JSONStruct]()

private func fetch() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "\(BaseURL.url)records.php"),
        else { return }
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = "page=\(var1)".data(using: .utf8)
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, error in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                self.structure = try JSONDecoder().decode([JSONStruct].self,from:data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                    
                }
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
            
        }.resume()
        
    }
```

**Response example:**

```
[
  {
    "code": "2423343",
    "checkbox": 0
  },
  {
    "code": "0902392",
    "checkbox": 1
  },
]
```

How can `allSatisfy` be used to identify if checkbox equals 1 for all records in array?

Comment: Have you ever read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994715-allsatisfy)? There is even an example.

Comment: Yes, I am struggling to reference the checkbox object from the structure. How can I direct the `Let` clause to it?
`let allCheckBoxes = structure.checkbox.allSatisfy({ $0 == 1 })`

Comment: Instead of counting the characters you want to check the `checkbox` property, so it’s  `let allCheckBoxes = structure.allSatisfy({ $0.checkbox == 1 })`. `allSatisfy` is always called on an array.

Comment: Because checkbox value is a bool I get the following error: `Value of type 'Bool' has no member 'allSatisfy'`

Comment: According to your code `checkbox` is `Int`. And – again – you have to call `allSatisfy` directly on `structure`. By the way I recommend to use a name which implies an array form example `items`.